# Intercept and customise Apollo GraphQL Errors

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo

I am using simple error handling mechanism based on ApolloError (or derived one) to throw errors from my GraphQL server. For example:

```
throw new AuthenticationError("Token not present in the request");
```

In this case, client would receive something like:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Token not present in the request",
      ...
```

I would like to somehow intercept those errors before returning the response to the client, in order to translate them to user's language of choice.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/errors/) you can provide the `formatError` method to your ApolloServer constructor.

```js
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  formatError: (err) => {
    if (err.message.includes("xyz")) {
      return new Error('Internal server error');
    }

    return err;
  },
});
```

> Use `err.originalError` to do type checking

```js
formatError: (err) => {
    if (err.originalError instanceof AuthenticationError) {
      return new Error('Internal server error');
    }

    return err;
  },
```

Comment: Seems like there is no access to the user context within this method. How can I personalise it?

Comment: @Aleks I don't believe you can access `context` from this method, you could throw custom errors that you manually construct with a `context` property... Something like `throw new MyError({msg: "", context: ctx})`